# Is it possible to add a column and remove double quotes without using a temp file?

Tags: powershell, csv

It seems that when I process an input, save it to a temp file, and then load that temp file to remove the double quotes - it works.

Is it possible to do this operation in on line?  When the code is un-commented below it fails.

Input file:

```
ICode,AccountNumber,Currency,TradeDateString,GrossAmount,BCode
CHK,953011,CAD,20160919,-20.17,N0
```

Code:

```
cls
$DebugPreference = 'Continue' 
cd "c:\_ps"

$InFile   = "trades_WithHeader.csv"
$OutFile  = "C:\_ps\trades_WithHeader_Manipulated2.csv"
$OutFile2 = "C:\_ps\trades_WithHeader_Manipulated4.csv"

$CSV = Import-Csv $InFile | select AccountNumber, @{Name="Name";Expression={$_.""}}

x=1;

foreach ($ReadData in $CSV) {$ReadData.Name=$x;$x++}

$CSV | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation 

# does not work - only "Length" column is output
#$CSV | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
#    % {$_ -replace '"', ""} |
#    % {$_ -replace '"', ""} |
#    Export-Csv $OutFile2 -NoTypeInformation 

Import-Csv $OutFile | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    % {$_ -replace '"', ""} |
    Out-File $OutFile2 -Force -Encoding Ascii

Invoke-Item $OutFile2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Out-File` (or equivalent cmdlets, like `Set-Content`, which uses ASCII encoding by default) is the correct way of writing CSV data to a file after you converted the data via `ConvertTo-Csv`.

The `Export-Csv` cmdlet expects a list of objects as input and writes the properties of the objects as the fields of the CSV. If you feed it the list of strings that `ConvertTo-Csv` produces it writes the sole property of those string objects (`Length`) to the output file.

To add an index column to your data you could do something like this:

```
$x = 1
Import-Csv $InFile | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        AccountNumber = $_.AccountNumber
        Name          = $x
    }
    $x++
} | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoType
```

If for some obscure reason you must remove the double quotes do it like this:

```
$x = 1
Import-Csv $InFile | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        AccountNumber = $_.AccountNumber
        Name          = $x
    }
    $x++
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '"', ''
} | Set-Content $OutFile
```

Note, however, that I do **NOT** recommend removing the double quotes from the CSV output. They're valid CSV syntax, and they're required if for instance you have string values with the delimiter character or nested double quotes in them.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I'm still seeing the double quotes, I would not expect version to have an influence - I'm working with version 2 of PowerShell.  I appreciate the caveat on the advisability of double quotes, that's the way to go but I'd still like to know how to control this.

Comment: *I'm still seeing the double quotes* That's because I neglected to actually put in the code that removes them. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I owe you one virtual beer, or beverage of your choice.

Comment: Nicely done; note that despite what the help for `Set-Content` states, it's actually the system's legacy single-byte codepage that is used (an encoding that PowerShell calls `Default`), which is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) for many Western European cultures; verify with `'Ä' | set-content tmp; fhx tmp`, which shows a single-byte encoding with `Ä` encoded as `0xc4` (if the encoding were truly strictly ASCII, the non-ASCII `Ä` would have been translated to _literal_ `?`).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $script:x=0
  import-csv $InFile | select AccountNumber , @{Name="Name";Expression={$script:x++; $script:x}} | export-csv -Path $InFile -NoTypeInformation
```

if you want really remove quote

```
  $script:x=0
  import-csv $InFile | select AccountNumber , @{Name="Name";Expression={$script:x++; $script:x}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File $InFile
```

Comment: Hi Esperento, I'm still getting the double quotes, I'm using version 2 of PowerShell, .    Thanks for your code ,I'm now to PowerShell and it's interesting to see the variation of syntax.  Regards

Comment: Hi, Export-csv is just conforming to the basic rules of CSV by enclosing fields that contain special characters in double-quotes. but i will modify my script for remove quote. I like too PowerShell because multiple syntax exists in this language :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I also owe you a virtual beer as well.

Comment: if you can accept my response, I also owe you a virtual beer as well :)

Comment: ugh, I can only mark one as accepted, your answer was just as useful however the other beat the clock by a little bit.  Thanks again

Comment: @Esperento57: As an aside: Your often useful answers are marred by pasting overly long lines that force readers to scroll horizontally, exacerbated by wasting 2 character positions on whitespace at the start of your code samples. Additionally, adding explanations would help more readers.

Comment: No reader never said that to me. Sorry for the long code, but if we powershell program with the code pipes quickly becomes long. And I do not have to sacrifice the emulation code with a form of pipe with "` ". In terms of space, I have to make my code indents (the function of the editor does not work very well I think) and sometimes there are one or two too many, but a pipe programming it would not change much.
Personally When I search something on stackoverflow, I do not like when there are unnecessary comments. I think comments should be there in some cases when the code is too complex

Comment: Are you moderator here?

Comment: I only came across your responses just now: you must @-mention others to have them notified of follow-up comments. No, I'm not a moderator, these were just my personal observations.
While people may not _tell_ you what they think of your posts, they may ignore them simply due to poor formatting and lack of explanations, even if the solutions are at their core helpful.
Note that you don't need backtick-escaping if you break your lines after the `|` symbol.

Comment: @mklement0,  i dont knew for the break line after | symbol ,ty